# (storing jQuery Objects) How big is each jQuery object, is it a bad idea to store these objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory

I am developing a single page HTML based application. I have different classes in my javascript for example one of my class is DataGridWidget.
Do you thin thinks it is a bad idea to store $jqObject in my calss object? is it heavy  (I might have something like 1000 objects from my classes which means 1000 pointer to jquery selector objects )

```
 DataGridWidget = function (parentWidget, id) {
         this.id = id;
         this.parentWidget = parentWidget;
         this.$jqObject = this.initUI();
  }

  DataGridWidget.prototype.initUI = function () {
        var $jqObject = $("<div class='datagrid_div' />");
        $("<table />").attr("id", this._getTableId()).appendTo($jqObject);
        $("<div />").attr("id", this._getPagerId()).appendTo($jqObject);
        $jqObject.attr("id", this.id);
        return $jqObject;
    }
```

Comment: It's not a bad idea, it's actually pretty common as long as you're clearing out the data when the element is removed (if that's even needed, in most cases it isn't)

Comment: The DOM elements already exist in memory anyways. Having another variables referring to them won't increase the memory footprint. But to be certain you can use Chrome's developer tools and profile the memory: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling.

Comment: @KevinB I know it is common for local variables in functions to cache jquery objects, but I doubted about long live class variables, you mean also for these kind of variables it is not bad?

Comment: jQuery plugins do this all the time. jQuery UI widgets All do this. Obviously just because someone else does it doesn't mean it's right, but you can come to your own conclusion on that through testing using the memory profiler.

Comment: I would suggest this though; if you're retreiving data with ajax and storing it in your class, when the table element is removed, make sure  that ajax data will be garbage collected properly.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right that objects are in DOM and one more pointer does not matter so much, but how about the whole jquery object it is not usually big for example a pointer to DOM and 10 pointers to something else (jquery version, ....)

Comment: Do a `console.dir(jqueryObject)` and have a look at the object's own properties. Those are the ones that take up memory (unless they are references to other objects). Everything else (under `__proto__`) is inherited from the prototype, is shared by all jQuery objects and exists only *once* in memory.